# Counting hours from a valid date

Tags: c#

I have a small problem because I do not always understand how to use the lessons of the day, for example, I want the time from the list to have the day time recalculated from that date, but if I have a new time, that conversion counts from the new time. It works fine for me if I only have one time, but if I have two times, `foreach` the loop calculates me both times for the day.

This is my code:

```
  public TimeSpan GetHoursForDay(DateTime day) {
         TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.Zero;

         foreach (var times in shouldWorkTime)
                {
                    if (times.Valid_from > day) //here's the real problem for me, do i want the hours to count from that date, for example: for 1.1.2020 it doesn't need to take hours from 1.12.2019
                        continue;
                    if (day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                    {
                        time += times.ShouldWorkMonday;
                    }
                    if (day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
                    {
                        time += times.ShouldWorkTuesday;
                    }
                    if (day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
                    {
                        time += times.ShouldWorkWednesday;
                    }
                    if (day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
                    {
                        time += times.ShouldWorkThursday;
                    }
                    if (day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
                    {
                        time += times.ShouldWorkFriday;
                    }
                    if (day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                    {
                        time += times.ShouldWorkSaturday;
                    }
                    if (day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                    {
                        time += times.ShouldWorkSunday;
                    }
                }
                return time;
            }
    }
```

These are the values I get in the list:

```
var shouldWorkTime = new List<ShouldWorkTime>
            {
             new ShouldWorkTime
             {
            Valid_from = new DateTime(2019, 12, 01, 0, 0, 0), 
            ShouldWorkMonday = new TimeSpan(8,0,0),
            ShouldWorkTuesday= new TimeSpan(7,0,0),
            ShouldWorkWednesday= new TimeSpan(6,0,0),
            ShouldWorkThursday= new TimeSpan(5,0,0),
            ShouldWorkFriday= new TimeSpan(8,0,0),
            ShouldWorkSaturday = new TimeSpan(0,0,0),
            ShouldWorkSunday = new TimeSpan(0,0,0)
            },
            new ShouldWorkTime
            {
            Valid_from = new DateTime(2020, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0), 
            ShouldWorkMonday = new TimeSpan(4,0,0),
            ShouldWorkTuesday= new TimeSpan(3,0,0),
            ShouldWorkWednesday= new TimeSpan(6,0,0),
            ShouldWorkThursday= new TimeSpan(5,0,0),
            ShouldWorkFriday= new TimeSpan(9,0,0),
            ShouldWorkSaturday = new TimeSpan(0,0,0),
            ShouldWorkSunday = new TimeSpan(0,0,0)
                }
            };
```

for the day value, I always get for the current day from the calendar, so I want to be counted in this case for the days of 1.1.2020 values for the days that fall in the second count, and until then the values that fall in the first count.

so i need to return how many hours for a particular day a worker needs to make, but valid from the last date from (Valid_From).

How can I correct this? thank you all very much for your help

eg:

> input 1.1.2020 output = 6,0,0;
>
> input 1.12.2019 output = 0,0,0;

Comment: Sorry, i read the question multiple time. It's still unclear, and hard to understand.  May you reduce and simplify to have [mre]? Perhaps you are just missing the else between the if..

Comment: @xdtTransform so i need to return how many hours for a particular day a worker needs to make but valid from the last date from (Valid_From)

Comment: @xdtTransform I do not know what is not clear to you, I try to make it as easy as possible, I should eventually return Time for a certain day of the week, but always valid from a certain date.

Comment: @Mara try to make us an example without code, I also did not understand your question.

Comment: @xdtTransform I corrected the question

Comment: @Mara, when you copy paste some code to have 7 times the (pretty) same code it's time to think of factorization. Maybe you should go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i really don't know what else i can fix on my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Mara an example without code, the input and the expected output.

Comment: @ilyes I added both input and output

Comment: Note that you didn't choose a revelant Input and output as they are different DayOfWeek. It don't show what was the `ShouldWorkTime` that provided the result.

Comment: @Orace, Code review is not from broken code. Only working code in on topic there. A link for "refactoring multiple if statement", "state pattern", "If switch case". Pointing to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a little modification of the Data structure.
Instead of a brunch of property The TimeSpan will be mapped to the DayOfWeek using a Dictionary. This will remove the need for a switch-case or a lot of If.
Using DayOfWeek as dictionary key ensure that only one TimeSpan is defined for a day.

```
public class WorkingTimeScheldure
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<DayOfWeek, TimeSpan> Scheldure { get; set; }
}
```

That way I can ask for the TimeSpan of a day using : `Scheldure[test.DayOfWeek]`

Note the addition of an End property. It may be usefull to select the right thing.
eg: 30/01/2020 is superior to 01/12/2019 and 01/01/2020..
So in order to take the most recent, I assume the list in ordered on Start date and pick the last one: `.Last(x => x.Start <= day)`.

[Online Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h9O8RL)

```
public class Program
{
    static List<ShouldWork> WorkTimeScheldure;
    public static void Main()
    {
        WorkTimeScheldure = new List<ShouldWork>
        {
            new ShouldWork
            {
                Start = new DateTime(2019, 12, 01, 0, 0, 0),
                Scheldure= new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, TimeSpan>()
                {
                    {(DayOfWeek)0,  new TimeSpan(0,0,0)},
                    {(DayOfWeek)1,  new TimeSpan(8,0,0)},
                    {(DayOfWeek)2,  new TimeSpan(7,0,0)},
                    {(DayOfWeek)3,  new TimeSpan(6,0,0)},
                    {(DayOfWeek)4,  new TimeSpan(5,0,0)},
                    {(DayOfWeek)5,  new TimeSpan(8,0,0)},
                    {(DayOfWeek)6,  new TimeSpan(0,0,0)}
                }
            },
            new ShouldWork
            {
                Start = new DateTime(2020, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0),
                Scheldure = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, TimeSpan>()
                {
                    {(DayOfWeek)0,  new TimeSpan(0,0,0)},
                    {(DayOfWeek)1,  new TimeSpan(4,0,0)},
                    {(DayOfWeek)2,  new TimeSpan(3,0,0)},
                    {(DayOfWeek)3,  new TimeSpan(6,0,0)},
                    {(DayOfWeek)4,  new TimeSpan(5,0,0)},
                    {(DayOfWeek)5,  new TimeSpan(9,0,0)},
                    {(DayOfWeek)6,  new TimeSpan(0,0,0)}
                }
            }
        };

        var testValues = new[] {

            new DateTime(2019, 12, 01, 0, 0, 0),
            new DateTime(2019, 12, 02, 0, 0, 0),
            new DateTime(2019, 12, 03, 0, 0, 0),
            new DateTime(2019, 12, 04, 0, 0, 0),
            new DateTime(2019, 12, 05, 0, 0, 0),
            new DateTime(2019, 12, 06, 0, 0, 0),
            new DateTime(2019, 12, 07, 0, 0, 0),
            new DateTime(2019, 12, 08, 0, 0, 0),

            new DateTime(2020, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0),
            new DateTime(2020, 01, 02, 0, 0, 0),
            new DateTime(2020, 01, 03, 0, 0, 0),
            new DateTime(2020, 01, 05, 0, 0, 0),
            new DateTime(2020, 01, 05, 0, 0, 0),
            new DateTime(2020, 01, 06, 0, 0, 0),
            new DateTime(2020, 01, 07, 0, 0, 0),
            new DateTime(2020, 01, 08, 0, 0, 0),
        };


        foreach (var test in testValues) {

            // Perhaps there is many possible, so I took the Last.
            var workingTime = WorkTimeScheldure.Last(x => x.Start <= day);
            //Please handle the case where there is no matching scheludre for this date.

            var houtToWork = workingTime.Scheldure[day.DayOfWeek].Hours;

            Console.WriteLine(
                $"{day.ToShortDateString()} , it's a {day.DayOfWeek}" +
                $" I have to work {houtToWork} Hour{(houtToWork>1?"s":"")}!"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Result :

```
12/01/2019 , it's a Sunday I have to work 0 Hour!
12/02/2019 , it's a Monday I have to work 8 Hours!
12/03/2019 , it's a Tuesday I have to work 7 Hours!
12/04/2019 , it's a Wednesday I have to work 6 Hours!
12/05/2019 , it's a Thursday I have to work 5 Hours!
12/06/2019 , it's a Friday I have to work 8 Hours!
12/07/2019 , it's a Saturday I have to work 0 Hour!
12/08/2019 , it's a Sunday I have to work 0 Hour!


01/01/2020 , it's a Wednesday I have to work 6 Hours!
01/02/2020 , it's a Thursday I have to work 5 Hours!
01/03/2020 , it's a Friday I have to work 9 Hours!
01/04/2020 , it's a Saturday I have to work 0 Hour!
01/05/2020 , it's a Sunday I have to work 0 Hour!
01/06/2020 , it's a Monday I have to work 4 Hours!
01/07/2020 , it's a Tuesday I have to work 3 Hours!
01/08/2020 , it's a Wednesday I have to work 6 Hours!
```

Comment: your code is good but i can't use Dictionary property, do i get from the database for every day the appropriate hours. Can you turn off Dictionary Property and get this result instead.

Comment: In your original Method add `var workingTime = shouldWorkTime.Last(x => x.Start <= day);` at the top. Remove the `foreach` (not it's containt). replace `+=` by `=`. You need no sum. voila

Comment: how can i restore timespan.Zero not to bug me on this part?
var workingTime = WorkingTimeScheldure.Last(x => x.Start <= day);
(System.InvalidOperationException: "The sequence does not contain a matching element.")

Comment: @Mara , Take this part and put in in horace answer where he used firstordefault. There is not mutch involved in our answer. and they pretty mutch match one for one. You should take a time a google for "linq" + one of the following {"OrderBy", "FirstOrDefault", "LastOrDefault",  "Last", "First"} in order to get a better understanding on how it work and what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The test `times.Valid_from > day` is `false` for all element in `shouldWorkTime` if the value of `day` is big enough. That why `time` can be incremented multiple time.

If you want to increment only once and on the first/last acceptable value of `Valid_from`, you should ensure that `shouldWorkTime` is sorted in increasing/decreasing order and ensure that the increment is done only once.

In fact you didn't need increment but just return the corresponding `TimeSpan`:

```
public TimeSpan GetHoursForDay(DateTime day) {
    // shouldWorkTime should have been sorted once for all at creation.
    // This code use the first acceptable Valid_from
    // By using OrderByDescending we take the last (in date) entry
    var math = shouldWorkTime
                 .Where(v => day >= v.Valid_from) // We take only valid entry
                 .OrderByDescending(v => v.Valid_from) // We sort only on valid entry
                 .FirstOrDefault(); // we take the last (in date) valid entry

    if (match == null)
        return TimeSpan.Zero;

    switch (day.DayOfWeek)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Monday:
            return match.ShouldWorkMonday;
        case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
            return match.ShouldWorkTuesday;
        case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
            return match.ShouldWorkWednesday;
        case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
            return match.ShouldWorkThursday;
        case DayOfWeek.Friday:
            return match.ShouldWorkFriday;
        case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
            return match.ShouldWorkSaturday;
        case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
            return match.ShouldWorkSunday;
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

To avoid code duplication, the `ShouldWorkTime` class may provide a `GetWorkTimeForDayOfWeek`:

```
public TimeSpan GetWorkTimeForDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
  ...
}
```

And instead of storing seven values in seven fields, you may take a look to collections. I will choose a [`Dictionary<DayOfWeek, TimeSpan>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: tell you the part where you do OrderBy (if I need it from your valid date), not always the last date, but if it's December 5, 2019 (valid for December 1, 2019), but if it's for 1.1.2020, then for him from 1.1.2020. With this code, I get a similar result.

Comment: I don't really get your point but from what I get, maybe try `.OrderByDescending(v => v.Valid_from).FirstOrDefault(v => v.Valid_from >= day);` with `>=` instead of `>`.

Comment: @Mara in your original question, you didn't provide the rule to apply for the selection of the `ShouldWorkTime` item in the list. Like "I want to use the last item (ordered by `Valid_from`) that as a `Valid_from` <=` to the current day."

Comment: +1. Imo, perfect solution. Selecting the right "match", I went for `.Last(x => x.Start <= day)`. And hinted that won't take responsibility over the order (asc/desc). Un code bien plus rigoureux. Bien moins condescendant que ma giffle "Change ton format de donnée". Pugnace le Horace.